# SSIS authorized access this information error

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

Error is as following:

> Description: Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password" with
>   error 0x8009000B "Key not valid for use in specified state.". You may
>   not be authorized to access this information. This error occurs when
>   there is a cryptographic error. Verify that

Comment: Is this a package that worked when you were designing it on your machine, but is giving this error when you've saved it to the server and are trying to run it from there?

Comment: No the package was created by another user.He was out of company right now so then onwards the package was not running .When i tried to debugg it iam getting the above error.@thursdaysgeek

Answer (score 0):

Right click on empty space in your package and select properties.
In the shown properties select package password as 'Dont save Sensitive' save the package and rebuild the entire project or solution and then save the package and close the ssis.

When you open again it asks for all the passwords.just provide all the passwords and it should work fine.